# Can you resize a Keynote slide without resizing text?

Tags: keynote

I'm currently using Keynote to layout a web design, but I've made my slide too short. When I try to resize my slide, all the text increases in size, destroying my layout.

So my question is, **is there a way to resize my slide without resizing the text?**

Comment: How do you re-size your slides?

Comment: @Michiel In Inspector > Document > Document > Slide Size > Custom slide size... Then increase the height.

Answer (score 8):

Keynote files are zipped XML files. I created some little Apple Script to resize keynote files.

Some caveats:

- It always resizes all slides, no selection possible. Maybe you can export the slides you want to resize to another file and only resize this, afterwards merging it back.
- It requires `xsltproc` which is not included in Mac OS X by default. Choose between

  - Install XCode (from [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835), command line tools only are fine, too) *or*
  - Install `libxslt`, eg. using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install libxslt`
- Following the comments, Apple changed the data format from Keynote '09 to the current version. Please save your document as a Keynote '09 document, as the script is not (yet) able to deal with the new format.

**Though I don't believe the script could mess anything up, please do a backup before applying it!**

[**keyresize now resides on github.**](https://github.com/JensErat/keyresize)

Comment: Thanks, saved me a bunch of copy/paste time!

Only problem with the script is you can't have spaces in the path to the Keynote file or itself. i.e. 'my keynote.key' won't work, but 'mykeynote.key' will.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue, I fixed it and pushed everything to github.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work for Keynote '09 only, however I was able to convert my doc back and forth to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I added it to the list of caveats.

Answer (score 7):

1. Select all the stuff on the page.
2. Cut it.
3. Change the doc size.
4. Paste it back.

Text comes in just like it was.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks!